# Como puedo insertar mi JSON en la base de datos

Tags: php, json

Tengo un JSON que en el cual obtengo datos desde el HTML y este tiene varios parámetros dentro intente con un foreach pero al parecer tengo mal planteado el recorrido del JSON

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
$Datos = json_decode($_POST['Datos'], true);
var_dump($Datos);
$ins = $conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO inventario(NProductos, CantidadComprada, Precio, Total) VALUES 
                         (:NProducto, :CantidadComprada , :Precio, :Total)");

 foreach ($Datos as $datos) {
    $ins->bindParam(":NProducto", $datos, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $ins->bindParam(":CantidadComprada", $datos, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $ins->bindParam(":Precio", $datos, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $ins->bindParam(":Total", $datos, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $ins->execute();
}
}
```

este es mi JSON que obtengo desde ajax

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según la imagen que muestras tu array es asociativo, o sea, tiene claves para cada valor. Entonces puedes acceder a los valores directamente por sus claves.

Así debería funcionar:

```
$ins->bindParam(":NProducto", $Datos["Nombre"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$ins->bindParam(":CantidadComprada", $Datos["cantidad"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$ins->bindParam(":Precio", $Datos["Precio"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$ins->bindParam(":Total", $Datos["Total"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$ins->execute();
```

**NÓTESE** que no se usa el ciclo `for` y que se usa la variable `$Datos` con `D` mayúscula, que es el propio array.

También, puedes dejarlo como JSON y usar la notación `$objeto->propiedad` para obtener los valores. A mí me gusta más este estilo:

```
#No pasamos true para que no lo convierta a array
$Datos = json_decode($_POST['Datos']);

$ins->bindParam(":NProducto", $Datos->Nombre, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$ins->bindParam(":CantidadComprada", $Datos->cantidad, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$ins->bindParam(":Precio", $Datos->Precio, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$ins->bindParam(":Total", $Datos->Total, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$ins->execute();
```

Comment: HAA ok , muchas gracias